# How to insert every value of an array into a js-function when the page load?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

//Connecting to my database.

```
include('connect.php');
```

//Setting up the query.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT address FROM restaurants");

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

$adresarray = array();

foreach ($result as $key) {
  $adresarray[] = ($key['adres']);
};
```

This array will be created when the page loads:

Array ( [0] => Address1 [1] => Address2 [2] => address3 [3] => Address4 [4] => Address5 [5] => Address6 [6] => Address6 [7] => Address7 )

I want to insert every Address value separately into a javascript function which calculates the longitude and latitude of the certain address and then shows the location in the google maps API. This all needs to happen when the page loads. 
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can convert the array to JSON object using json_encode function and use the JSON object in the javascript function

Comment: @KalyanSrinivasLimkar Thanks.

Comment: @kefaaah can you mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the array to JSON object using json_encode function and use the JSON object in the javascript function